# Migrating to Gradle Catalogs from BuildSrc in android studio -> "unknown property libraries"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to migrate my project from BuildSrc for libraries etc to Gradles "new" Catalogs. But I keep running in to the following error when building:

> Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for extension 'libs' of
> type org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs.

Gradle `7.5.1` is running on the project.

I have created `./gradle/libs.libraries.toml` which only has one library for testing and looks like this:

```
[libraries]
somelib = { module = "androidx.annotation:annotation", version = "1.4.0" }
```

and in a module build.gradle file I'm trying the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation libs.libraries.somelib
}
```

But when building the project it keeps crashing on the implementation line saying that `libraries` is an unknown property. `libs` however is found.

I have done all the usual cleaning of the project but this persists. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the 'libraries' part:

```
dependencies {
    implementation libs.somelib
}
```